# Why was I forced to set the bounty to 50 reputation when I had 78?

Tags: bug, questions

I was forced on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1723145/1678725) to set the bounty to 50 when I had 78, Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I was forced to set the bounty to 50 when I had 78, Why?

Bounties must be increments of 50: 50, 100, 150 etc so you cannot set a bounty of 78 and you don't have enough reputation to set a bounty of 100.

See [How does the bounty system work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)